# What is the best way to synchronize users and groups using Google Directory API

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-directory-api

We have to get the latest update about users and groups with [Google directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/) asap.

For users, we now save the "Etag" in the response of [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list), [groups.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list) and [members.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) in the first synchronization. Then the etag will be checked every a few seconds, when it changes, we will invoke paged calls `users.list`, `groups.list` or `members.list` again to get the updates.

It works well for small domains, but it will be a problem for big domains (the amount of user could be 60000 and the amount of group could be 10000 with 1000 members in each group). When there is a little change in a single user or group, the etag will change. So we have to invoke the paged calls again and again.

So the question is: Is there a better way that we can get the small changes more efficient?

Comment: For users changes, you can use push notifications instead of just depending on etag. check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push . But for groups and members as there is no watch method you have to follow the same mentioned above.

Comment: @SGC Thank you. The push notifications is a very solution to update the users. Just wander why google doesn't push notifications for change of group and member